# d prime for false alarm rate greater than hit rate in R

Tags: r, psychopy

I've collected some data from an apparently quite difficult ABX task. I was intending to use psyphy::dprime.ABX, but was receiving the error `Only valid for Pc.unb > 0.5`.

As an example, for one participant has a hit rate of .486, and a false alarm rate of .569, so `psyphy::dprime.ABX(.486, .569)` returns the error above.

Questions:

1. Can such d primes be calculated with psyphy?
2. Someone suggested flipping the hits and FA and changing the sign of the result.  Is this valid?
3. Does anyone know a preferred method for calculating ABX d primes in this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we start with bayes theorem:

```
P(yes|present) P(present)  = P(yes|absent) P(absent)
```

then

```
P(yes|present) = P(yes|absent) P(absent)/P(present)
```

So if Hits (P(yes|present)) and Fa (P(yes|absent)) are almost the same then P(absent) and P(present) are almost the same too. Is such case this is like a flipping a correct coin.

The source code of the function:
https://github.com/cran/psyphy/blob/5b170ead1580c09c1359b2db3855514d71f4420d/R/dprime.ABX.R

your P.unb:

```r
> Hits = .486
> FA = .569                      
> zdiff <- qnorm(Hits) - qnorm(FA)
> Pc.unb <- pnorm(zdiff/2)
> Pc.unb
[1] 0.4584004
```

Where the expected Pc_unb should be at least 0.5.
Thus the algorithm not work for a case where Hits < FA.
In such case we could not get any valuable feedback from this subject. In my opinion assuming a zero value for such cases might be a right decision. This is a assessment for certain subjects so the rest still should provide some valuable data. Then if data are zaero-inflated models like zero-inflated regression could be used.

Ps.

You could always provide Pc_unb directly:

```r
> psyphy::dprime.ABX(Pc.unb = 0.5)
[1] 0
> psyphy::dprime.ABX(Pc.unb = 0.51)
[1] 0.3319297
> psyphy::dprime.ABX(Pc.unb = 0.52)
[1] 0.4723176
> psyphy::dprime.ABX(Pc.unb = 0.53)
[1] 0.5821447
```